# How to install & start all OSGi bundles (JAR) automatically from a folder in WSO2 OSGi console?

Tags: osgi, wso2

```
osgi> install file:D:\f1\*.jar
osgi> install --start file:D:\f1\*.jar
```

Above commands is illegal in WSO2 OSGi console.
How to install & start all OSGi bundles (JAR) automatically from a folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install a single bundle file using the osgi command: install file:<full-path-to-bundler>.
If you need to install a set of bundles at once, you can copy the new bundles to <CARBON_HOME>/repository/components/dropins and start the server.

Thanks,
Dileepa

Answer (score 4):

Look at Apache Fileinstall ...

Comment: I will RTFriendlyM in next time